# Is there a native way to identify if attachments in Salesforce are password protected?

Tags: apex, passwords

I want to write logic in Salesforce to identify if an attachment stored in Salesforce is password protected or not.

From my research, this is NOT possible natively in Salesforce and that the solution would seem to be rather to create an external micro-service which receives blob data that is POST'd from Salesforce and then uses some methods available in other languages and/or third party libraries to identify if a file is password protected or not.

Can one advise if this is in fact feasible natively? I don't think it is but worth an ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native code that you can just call to determine if a file is password protected. Password protection is implemented in different ways in different file types. For example, ZIP and PDF use two different schemes.

You can read the specifications for a file type to figure out how detect password protection, but it will be a manual process. For example, I invented a way to detect [signed PDFs in native Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/18027/2984). It's very manual, and limited in file size, but it is possible.

Calling an external service is generally ideal, because otherwise you're having to reinvent the wheel for each file type. That said, it's mostly a matter of figuring out the correct signatures to look for, and then using a relatively simple search function. Most of the time you'll spend is researching an appropriate signature to look for.

Some file formats may have specific bits/bytes set at specific locations you can look for, so it might be easier to detect password-protected files of some types with just a few lines of code. Other systems encrypt key bytes, so you might also be able to just determine if those bytes do *not* match the expected signature, and you'll know it's encrypted (or not the right file type).